# IIS Rewrite - Add WWW but not to subdomains

Tags: mod-rewrite, iis

I run an online service where I recently added an AWS Load Balancer.

Before, everything was running on domains without www, but due to the AWS ELB can change its IP, we have to run the setup with CNAME records instead of A records.
CNAME records cannot point to the root domain. So I have to rewrite everything to www.

We have multiple customers and about 50% of them use their own domain, the rest is running as a subdomain to our main domain.

What I need is:

```
example.com -> www.example.com  
www.example.com -> www.example.com  
customer1.ourdomain.com --> customer1.ourdomain.com  
customer2.ourdomain.com --> customer2.ourdomain.com
```

I am not the best in setting up rules for IIS rewrite in web.config, but I hope that someone can point me to the correct solution.

Previously we've been running with this, for removing www, but now I need the opposite.

```
    <rule name="Remove www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.+)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Everything is running http (for now).

Answer (score 0):

```
    <rule name="Add www">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^ourdomain\.com" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}{UNENCODED_URL}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```